# Mapping 2 different 2-dimensional arrays together in Vue

Tags: api, vuejs3

I'm new to Vue and programming in general so please understand if I'm doing something dumb. I'm fetching data from 2 apis and storing them into arrays. I want to map 2 arrays together with the attribute url from photos and attributes username and name from users then store the result in userData.

This is my code. If I left something out, sorry in advance - it's my first time posting here.

```
const app = Vue.createApp({

        data() {
            return {
                users: [],
                photos: [],
                userData: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async loadUsers() {
                const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
                const finalRes = await res.json();
                this.users = finalRes;
                console.log(finalRes);
            },
            async loadPictures() {
                const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
                const finalRes = await res.json();
                
                this.photos = finalRes;
                this.photos = this.photos.slice(0,10);
                console.log("pictures");
                console.log(this.photos);
            },
            mapPicture() {
                userData = this.photos.map(function (x, i) {
                    return { 
                            "profilePic": x, 
                            "name": this.user.name[i], 
                            "username": this.user.username[i] }
                }.bind(this));
                console.log("Mapping");
                console.log(userData);
        
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.loadUsers(),
            this.loadPictures()
            this.mapPicture()
        },
    computed: {
        GetUsers: function () {
            return this.users;
        },
        GetPictures: function () {
            return this.photos;
        }
    }
}).mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose imagining the json of users and the photos are something as below

```
var users = [
    {
        name: 'Pushpraj',
        userName: 'PR',
    },
    {
        name: 'Raj',
        userName: 'RAJ21',
    },
];
var photos = [
    {
        URL: 'URL1',
    },
    {
        URL: 'URL2',
    },
    
];
```

Instead of `map()`, let's use `forEach()`. Your logic should be as below

```
var users = [
    {
        name: 'Pushpraj',
        userName: 'PR',
    },
    {
        name: 'Raj',
        userName: 'RAJ21',
    },
];
var photos = [
    {
        URL: 'URL1',
    },
    {
        URL: 'URL2',
    },
    
];

var userData = [];
users.forEach((user, index) => {
    userData.push({
        name: user.name,
        userName: user.userName,
        profilePic: photos[index].URL,
    })    
});
console.log(userData);
```